# Nginx proxy files

Tags: nginx, proxy, rules

i go to php-fpm

now have image urls like:

```
https://site1.me/i/img/img.site2.ru/cat1/cat2/cat3/picname.big.jpg
```

fact url of image:

```
img.site2.ru/cat1/cat2/cat3/picname.big.jpg
```

i need proxy this image from site1

on apache all is ok  whith .htaccess in /i/

```
RewriteEngine on
php_value default_socket_timeout 1

RewriteRule "^img/(.*)$" "http://$1" [P] 
RewriteRule "^imgs/(.*)$" "https://$1" [P]
```

how do it on nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this config:

```
server {
    ...
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "default_socket_timeout=1";
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    ...
    location ~ ^/i/img/([^/]+)(.*) {
        proxy_set_header Host $1;
        proxy_pass http://$1$2;
    }

    location ~ ^/i/imgs/([^/]+)(.*) {
        proxy_set_header Host $1;
        proxy_pass https://$1$2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forget about `resolver` parameter. You need to specify it when your proxy domain is a variable string. You can use your local name server if you have one, or use something external like Google public DNS (8.8.8.8) or DNS provided for you by your ISP. See updated answer.